# Charles Proxy: Genymotion with certificate pinning

Tags: android, proxy, certificate-pinning

Is there anyway I can use charles proxy with an android app that is using certificate pinning? I read this thread: http://blog.attify.com/2015/08/24/intercepting-network-traffic-android/ and it says that you can do it but the SSL TrustKiller it is referring to is about 2 years old and I don't think it works with the newer versions of android api 22: https://github.com/iSECPartners/Android-SSL-TrustKiller

When I install both Cydia Substrate and SSL TrustKiller on my Genymotion emulator, I cannot seem to link the substrate, it just gives me an error in Cydia Substrate:

[image]

As  workaround for now, I'm turning off SSL on both my debug server and android app so that Charles Proxy will pick up my traffic.